# I am struggling with the requirejs optimizer and non AMD modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, require

I am struggling with the requirejs optimizer. This code will work if I just load it in the browser without optimization. If I run the optimizer I get

```
: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\dev\checkout\src\main\webapp\resources\scripts\
json2.js'

In module tree: main
```

This is the code

```
requirejs.config({
paths : {
    jquery : "lib/jquery",
    bootstrap : "lib/bootstrap",
    modals : "lib/modals",
    tablesort : "lib/tablesort",
    json2 : "lib/json2"
},

shim : {
    "bootstrap" : [ "jquery" ],
    "modals" : [ "jquery" ],
    "tablesort" : [ "jquery" ],
    "json2" : [ "jquery" ]
}
});

require([ "jquery", "json2","bootstrap", "modals", "tablesort", "registermodule",    "personsmodule" ], function($) {
```

What needs to be done to get the optimizer working? I tried putting lib/json2 in the require. Then I get jQuery issues because it is non AMD modules.

Edit: still struggling with this one. Tried the simpliest example. Works fine in browser but the optimizer complains about not finding the files. lib/jquery.js and lib/modal.js.

```
requirejs.config({
paths : {
    jquery : "lib/jquery",
    modals : "lib/modals"
},

shim : {
    "bootstrap" : [ "jquery" ],
    "modals" : [ "jquery" ]
}
});

require([ "jquery", "modals" ], function($) {

console.log($("#leverandor_span").text());
$("#register_modal").modal("show");

});
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem! Any progress?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem: the require.config() is not parsed by r.js. That configuration is only for runtime. For r.js we need to create another file to configure the paths and other stuff.

#### Create a file (e.g app.build.js) and configure the paths

```
({
   appDir: "../",
   baseUrl: "./",
   dir: "dist",
   modules: [
        {
            name: "bootloader"
        }
    ],
    paths: {
       // libraries path
      "json": "lib/json2",
      "jquery": "lib/jquery",
      "underscore": "lib/underscore",
      "bootstrap": "lib/bootstrap",
      "backbone": "lib/backbone",
      "hogan": "lib/hogan",

       // require plugins
      "css": "lib/css",
      "hgn": "lib/hgn",
      "text": "lib/text"
   }
})
```

#### run the optimizer:

> $r.js -o app.build.js

More details here: 
http://japhr.blogspot.it/2011/12/optimizing-requirejs-part-2.html

Build file options:
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject

Answer (score 24):

See [`mainConfigFile`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27). This was put into place so you do not have to copy your require configuration into runtime/optimize-time files, keeping your build DRY:

```
//By default all the configuration for optimization happens from the command
//line or by properties in the config file, and configuration that was
//passed to requirejs as part of the app's runtime "main" JS file is *not*
//considered. However, if you prefer the "main" JS file configuration
//to be read for the build so that you do not have to duplicate the values
//in a separate configuration, set this property to the location of that
//main JS file. The first requirejs({}), require({}), requirejs.config({}),
//or require.config({}) call found in that file will be used.
mainConfigFile: '../some/path/to/main.js',
```

Comment: I didn't know that. This is a very convenient to keep things simple while in dev stage. Nice.